# List all the leap years from now to the certain number the user inputed

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function that determines which of the next n years is a leap year. If the caller passes in 300, then the program should return the leap years between 2016 and 2316.

Leap Years are any year that can be evenly divided by 4 (such as 2012, 2016, etc) except if it can be evenly divided by 100, then it isn't (such as 2100, 2200, etc) except if it can be evenly divided by 400, then it is (such as 2000, 2400).

My first attempt was this :

```
 function leapYear(number) {
     var year = 2016 + number;
     var tracker = [];
     for(i = 2016; i <= year; i++) {
         if(i % 100 !== 0) {
             tracker.push(i);
         } else if(i % 400 === 0) {
             tracker.push(i);
         } else if(i % 4 === 0) {
             tracker.push(i);
         } else {
             return tracker;
         }
     }
     return tracker;

 }
 console.log(leapYear(300));
```

I realized that was wrong because I was not using if else statments properly, when you put a condition on else if it means the if statement condition was not met. This was my second attempt.

```
function leapYear(number) {
    var year = 2016 + number;
    var tracker = [];
    for(i = 2016; i <= year; i++) {
        if(i % 4 === 0 || i % 400 === 0 && i % 100 !== 0) {
            tracker.push(i);
        } else {
            return tracker;
        }
    }
}
console.log(leapYear(300));
```

I've tried several combinations like this but nothing has worked. And can someone tell me why this only prints out [2016]?

Comment: Do not `return` in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

try using `continue` instead of `return`, the updated code would be the following:

```
function leapYear(number){
    var year = 2016 + number;
    var tracker = [];
    for(i=2016 ; i <= year ; i++ ){
      if(i % 4 ===0 || i % 400 ===0 && i % 100 !== 0){
          tracker.push(i);
      }
      else{
        continue;
      }
    }
    return tracker;
}

console.log(leapYear(300));
```

Comment: You can do it even without the `else`.